# Model loading freeze scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

My scene temporary freeze during the loading time of my model. Are there any options in preventing this?

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load("model.js", function(smooth) {
  smooth.mergeVertices();
  smooth.computeFaceNormals();
  smooth.computeVertexNormals();
  var modifier = new THREE.SubdivisionModifier(1);
  modifier.modify(smooth);
  scene.add(smooth);
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(smooth, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color : 0x222222
  }));
  $('input').change(function() {
    if ($("#radio1, #radio2, #radio3, #radio4").is(":checked")) {
      scene.add(vierring);
    } else if ($("#radio1, #radio2, #radio3, #radio4").is(":not(:checked)")) {
      scene.remove(vierring);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: webworkers ? :) I haven't tried it yet but I have read that it prevents freezing, I plan to use it soon. Let me know if they solve this !

Comment: Thank you! Do you have an example for this?

Comment: How big is your model?

Comment: My model size is 1MB.

Comment: a 1MB model is not considered big.